# How do I assert an Error with Chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm lost with this and I've been right through the documentation and I can;t wrap my head around it.

I'm trying to write a test that checks that a method throws an error like this...

```
       it("requires an soCode parameter", () => {
            let readyStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, '_executeWhenReady');
            expect(objUt.mapStopsAroundHub(undefined, testPostCode)).to.throw("The 'soCode' parameter is required");
            readyStub.restore();
        });
```

This fails because it seems to want the function not the function execution - I changed the code as follows...

```
       it("requires an soCode parameter", () => {
            let readyStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, '_executeWhenReady');
            expect(objUt.mapStopsAroundHub).to.throw("The 'soCode' parameter is required");
            readyStub.restore();
        });
```

This works fine to check the first parameter (as I now can't provide any) but I'm out of luck with parameter number two...

```
       it("requires an param2 parameter", () => {
            let readyStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, '_executeWhenReady');
            expect(objUt.mapStopsAroundHub).to.throw("The 'param2' parameter is required", "VALUE", undefined);
            readyStub.restore();
        });
```

(I tried adding the parameters to the throw call but that doesn't work - It's not in the docs that I could see so that's not surprising).

I then thought to try wrapping the function call...

```
       it("requires an param2 parameter", () => {
            let readyStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, '_executeWhenReady');
            expect(() => objUt.mapStopsAroundHub("VALUE", undefined)).to.throw("The 'param2' parameter is required");
            readyStub.restore();
        });
```

but that failed because the function I wrapped it with isn't throwing the error.

Surely something like this should be really simple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK -  I was obviously just tired! The function wrap approach was the right way to go but I forgot the curly braces.

```
it("requires an param2 parameter", () => { let readyStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, '_executeWhenReady'); expect(() => { objUt.mapStopsAroundHub("VALUE", undefined);} ).to.throw("The 'param2' parameter is required"); readyStub.restore(); });
```